# How to connect two EC2 instances using the eth1 interface on both instances?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nic, interface

I have 2 EC2 instances running Ubuntu 18.04. I've attached an additional network interface "eth1" to each instance, so each instance has 2 interfaces( eth0, eth1). eth0 is the default gateway.

What I'm trying to do is to attach eth1 from instance 1 to eth1 from instance 2.

Answer (score 1):

Put interfaces that should talk to each other into the same subnet, with security groups that allow the required flows.